# Microsoft Digital Signature Expiration in Active Directory

Tags: microsoft-office, active-directory, certificate, digital-signature

We have a large number of users on our network that need to sign forms digitally from time to time with Microsoft digital signatures that are set up to expire each year. Some of our users however are little better than trained monkeys when it comes to computing skills and will panic if they see any message or error out of the ordinary.
So my question is:

Is there a way within active directory to check users signature certificates to see if they have expired or are close so that I can renew them for the user?